# Export php array data into excel

Tags: php, arrays, excel, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am trying to export my array result into excel using php excel.I want to put this data into multiple sheets based array. For eg: In array, person_mast,person_ex should be sheet1 and sheet2 and their respective array should be put with array key as heading of columns and array values as data in multiple rows in excel file.

**Problem :**

```
Not able to loop through array and put values in cells.
```

My array :

```
Array
(
[person_mast] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [details_id] => 10470
                [head_id] => 1
                [recdate] => 2011-02-23 00:00:00
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [details_id] => 38708
                [head_id] => 1
                [recdate] => 
            )
    )

[person_ex] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [details_id] => 9842
                [head_id] => 19
                [visit_dt] => 2014-08-07 00:00:00
                [addinfo] => abc
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [details_id] => 10234
                [head_id] => 20
                [visit_dt] => 2007-11-20 00:00:00
                [addinfo] => 3 3
            )

    )
)
```

My Code  :

```
    $filename = "report_".date('Ymd_His').".xls";
    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $sheet_count = '0';
    foreach($patient_result as $tb_name => $tb_data){
        $sheetname = $tb_name ;
        if($sheet_count != '0'){
            // Create a new worksheet, after the default sheet
            $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
        }
        // Create a first sheet, representing sales data
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheet_count);

        $column_count = 0;
        foreach($tb_data as $key => $curr_data){
                foreach($curr_data as $colname => $data){
                    //echo "<br>colname : ".$colname;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colname.$key, $data);
                    $column_count ++;
                }
        } 
        // Rename sheet
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($sheetname);

        $sheet_count++;
```

Expected Excel file format :

[image]

Comment: What is happening?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @Alex i have updated my code and have specified the problem and error. Please help.Thanks

Comment: Did you debug? Your error is not a specific error so I can't help you fix this.

Comment: Notice that sheet_count define as string - it should be int as column_count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheet number must be integer, increment operator work only with int val. must define header part (column name of each sheet) and need to pass sheet number to fill data which one currently in loop.

Just put this code and it will work 100%

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();


        $filename = "report_".date('Ymd_His').".xls";

        $sheet_title = array('person_mast','person_ex');            

       $sheet_count = 0;
       foreach($patient_result as $tb_name => $tb_data){


            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet($sheet_count);

           $header_key = array_keys($tb_data[0]);

            $header = array($header_key[0], $header_key[1], $header_key[2]);
            $list = array ($header);
            //$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheet_count);
            $sheet->setTitle($sheet_title[$sheet_count]);

            $tmp_row = array();
            foreach($tb_data as $key => $curr_data){
                //echo '<pre>'; print_r( $curr_data); exit;
                $list[] = $curr_data;
            }

            $sheet->fromArray($list);
        $sheet_count++; //break;

    }


    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');

    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
    //save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
    //if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

    //force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
    //$objWriter->save('php://output');

       $objWriter->save($filename);
```

Comment: It is preferred to explain what the code in question was missing so one could learn...

Comment: Sheet number must be integer, increment operator work only with int val.  must define header part (column name of each sheet) and need to pass sheet number to fill data which one currently in loop. please do upvote  if it works thanks.

Comment: @rahul i can't take header part as static. I want header to be made of inner array keys.

Comment: Somewhere you have to define your column name, my code is working fine now you have to use according to your requirement.

Comment: Just edited the code, try now hope it fulfill your requirement .

Comment: @Rahulkalal i have made header changes .PLease let me know if it is correct way and it almost worked . But when the document is downloaded forcefully the data becomes corrupted. Is there anyway to stop download and save directly to path specified ?

Comment: @Rahulkalal Or how can i get correct data while forcefull Download. Thanks

Comment: Just edit last line to save file. you will get your file into root folder. if you want to save in any specific folder then you  have to write folder path in $filename variable. don't forget to upvote thanks

Comment: PHP is weakly typed. String 0 will be cast to integer zero when increment operator is used.